# How to do sql select to join only unique rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables (animal, ability and can) on postgresql and need to select only UNIQUE values for the left join. How to do it?

**Query #1**

```
select * from animal;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dog |
| 2 | bird |
| 3 | fish |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from ability;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | breathe below the surface |
| 2 | fly |
| 3 | swim |
| 4 | bark |
| 5 | see |

---

**Query #3 (mapping table) - all abilities **

```
select
    animal.name as animal,
    ability.name as can,
    animal.id as animal_id,
    ability.id as ability_id
from can
inner join animal on animal.id = can.animal_id
inner join ability on ability.id = can.ability_id;
```

| animal | can | animal_id | ability_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dog | swim | 1 | 3 |
| dog | bark | 1 | 4 |
| dog | see | 1 | 5 |
| bird | fly | 2 | 2 |
| bird | see | 2 | 5 |
| fish | breathe below the surface | 3 | 1 |
| fish | swim | 3 | 3 |
| fish | see | 3 | 5 |

---

**REQUESTED RESULT - ONLY UNIQUE ABILITIES**

| animal | can |
| --- | --- |
| dog | bark |
| bird | fly |
| fish | breathe below the surface |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSmUVytu22vTdho9ogWfyq/4)

Comment: GROUP BY can, use MIN/MAX and HAVING.

Comment: So what is the rule to choose `bark` over `see` in the output for dog?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see is NOT UNIQUE for the dog as bird and fish can both see as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    animal.name as animal,
    ability.name as can
from can
inner join animal on animal.id = can.animal_id
inner join ability on ability.id = can.ability_id
where not exists (select 1 from can c where c.animal_id <> can.animal_id and c.ability_id = can.ability_id) 
;
```